# Zip a parent directory with files and child directories in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version

Is there a way to ONLY zip files and directories at the same time. I was using ZipArchive but is not working for Directories. The directory that I want to add in the Zip file has more directories and a zip file inside, so it's a nested directory. Can someone please assist.

```
using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
     {
      foreach (FileInfo file in filesToZip)
      {
       zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(Path.Combine(filePath, file.Name), file.Name);
      }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`?

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(filePath, zipFilePath);
```

If you need to zip up an entire directory (including sub-folders), this may be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

To create an empty file or directory, use [CreateEntry(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158346.aspx)

Include the slash for directories

```
zipArchive.CreateEntry(@"DirectoryName\");
```

Comment: zipArchive.CreateEntry() creates an empty entry. i need a zip entry with files.

Comment: ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(filePath, zipFilePath) worked if the zip file is located in a different directory